# Moto E being charged for mobile data even if it's turned off on Vodafone Karnataka SIM

Tags: mobile-data, dual-sim, motorola-moto-e

I have very recently purchased **Moto E** and using **Vodafone Karnataka SIM**. I have disabled mobile data and work only with WiFi.

Even after this, I see I am being charged with 0 MB data usage.

[image: Session cost: 0.04INR]
<sup>(Click for full size)</sup>

I don't understand what is happening here. It is coming very frequently. I am very sure none of the apps are using it since I uninstalled almost every app that I installed after this problem has arisen. I have checked data usage logs and it says 0 MB data usage and that none of my app have used any mobile data.

Why is this happening? Probably some check after WiFi gets disconnected? I checked with Android debugger, but there is too many log statement. Anything particular I should be looking at?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: This is essentially a Billing question, which should be resolved with your carrier. It concerns details private only to you concerning your specific usage and the details of your contract.

Comment: I already I said that I have turned off mobile data. And carrier should not be a problem.I wish to know what could be the possible reason for this? Any android service or setting doing this?

Comment: Dial `*123*10#`, see what that says, and then dial `*123*11#` and see what that says. Keep us posted!

Comment: "carrier should not be a problem" – umm, and who then is charging you if not the carrier? Who else might send that billing information?

Comment: Leaving this question open, because some of the answers makes sense, esp on dual SIM. I'd like to see what the OP has to say, and what he's done based on the given answers.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, it's apparent that you're using a dual SIM phone and that Data Roaming is enabled on one of those SIM cards.

I've never used a dual SIM phone but I read on a forum that at any point of time only one of the SIM cards can be used for data while the other is on standby or being used for a voice call.

Make sure both your SIM cards have Data disabled. Also disable Data Roaming for both SIM cards.

Use these screenshots for reference (click for full size):

1. Check your data usage in `Settings`→`Data usage` to see what's using your data connection
   [image: Mobile data usage]
2. Make sure `Data roaming` is disabled for both SIM cards 
   [image: Disable data roaming]

Answer (score 0):

Install Greenify. It will stop all background processes and save memory, battery and unwanted network connectivity.

Answer (score -1):

After using Mobile network and you disabled it , you will receive a notification in black background about your Balance internet GB/MB or charged price for internet usage (as like what you received now in the picture)

Comment: That is what.. even after disabling mobile network I am getting this... that too repeatedly... Something in background is doing this and I wish to know what?

Answer (score -1):

Airtel system has some bugs. the usage is not shown properly and i will advise to install an app that would manage your data account. which can show your real usage.

Comment: Could you name any such reliable app?

Comment: I personally use My Data manager. @AniketThakur and do vote me up:P